# How can I load the content from scratch on each tab click when using v-tabs in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

**Problem Statement :**

I'm using `v-tabs` feature in my vue.js project. I want the content to be run over and over again every time I click on the tab.

**Template :**

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <!-- add tab feture -->
    <v-tabs color="#F65C38" left v-model="tab">
      <v-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item.tab">
        {{ item.tab }}
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
      <v-tab-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.tab">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>
            <component v-bind:is="item.content"></component>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs-items>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

**Data :**

```
tab: null,
items: [
  { tab: 'tab1', content: 'test1' },
  { tab: 'tab2', content: 'test2' },
  { tab: 'tab3', content: 'test3' },
],
```

For example, when I first open the page and click on tab 1, I switch to tab 2 and when I click on tab 1 again, the content is not called again, the old one appears.

Comment: maybe you could add a `v-if` on the element before `v-tab-item` or on the `<v-card>` to force a reload.

Comment: bind component with key like   <component v-bind:is="item.content" :key="compKey"></component> and increment compKey variable after each click

Answer (score -1):

Since you have your `component` inside a for loop, every element is already rendered and the `v-tab` just controls what is displayed.

But you can use `v-tab` without `v-tabs-items`. With the v-model `tab` you can control which component the `component` should be.

Your example would look like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <!-- add tab feture -->
    <v-tabs color="#F65C38" left v-model="tab">
      <v-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item.tab">
        {{ item.tab }}
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <component v-bind:is="items[tab].content" :key="tab"></component>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-card>
</template>
```